# Test for one forEach loop in Jasmine (Isolated Test)

Tags: angular, loops, testing, foreach, jasmine

I'm trying to test the code inside a forEach loop but I can't. I tried something I found on https://testing-angular.com/ but I can't get into those lines as you can see in the coverage report.

**This is my component code**

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    ...

    let lightRes= [
      {
        children: [{Id: 10, name: "test"}],
        startDate: "",
        description: "",
        id: 111,
        title: "test for light",
      },
    ];

    const res = {data: lightRes};

    component.lightService.lightDetail.and.returnValue(
      scheduled([res], asyncScheduler)
    );

  });

  private getLights(id: string): void {
    const sus = this.lightService.lightDetail(id).subscribe((light) => {
      this.light = new Light(light.data);
      this.light.children.forEach((val) =>
        this.clonedArray.push(Object.assign({}, val))
      );
      this.light.fathers = light.data.fathers;
    });
    this.suscripciones.add(sus);
  }
```

**This is my Spec.ts code**

```
  it("getLights", fakeAsync(() => {
    component.getLight();
    res.data[0].children.forEach((val) => {});
    tick();
  }));
```

**This is my code coverage**

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `light` inside of the `subscribe`? Make sure that `new Light(light.data)` returns something that causes `this.light.children` to be a non-empty array.

Comment: I created a mock for lightDetail. I guess light should have that value. I edit it to look like I created this mock.

Comment: That was just the problem, I was passing an array instead of an object, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that it was sending the data as an array and not as a single object, that's why the empty data arrived.
`

```
 let lightRes= {
    children: [{Id: 10, name: "test"}],
    startDate: "",
    description: "",
    id: 111,
    title: "test for light",
  };`
```